# Python Gerar layout txt a partir de um arquivo txt

Tags: python, txt

Tenho um arquivo txt que estou fazendo tratamento para gerar um layout em outro arquivo txt. Quando uso o comando `print` o mesmo gera corretamente, porém quando coloco para escrever em outro arquivo ele gera somente a primeira linha.

```
num = input ("Digite local: ")
num2 = input ("Digite sub local: ")
f = open("update_teste.txt","w+")
with open ('contagem.txt') as fo:
    for s in fo:
        print  ("0",num, num2, s[0:12], s[14:19], sep="")
new = ("0"+ num+ num2+ s[0:12]+ s[14:19])
with open ("update_teste.txt", "w+") as arquivo:
    arquivo.writelines (str(new))
    print (new)
```

Arquivo contagem.txt:

```
1234567890128;00001
5687544567456;00001
7898433340878;00002
8888021201451;00002
```

update_teste.txt:

```
00100588880212014500002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está lendo todo o arquivo e depois só guarda a última linha em `new` (pois ela está fora do `for` que lê o arquivo, e depois do `for` a variável `s` terá a última linha que foi iterada, todas as anteriores já foram "perdidas", pois você só as imprimiu mas não guardou-as em nenhum lugar).

Enfim, se quer ler de um arquivo enquanto escreve no outro, faça tudo no mesmo *loop*:

```
num = input ("Digite local: ")
num2 = input ("Digite sub local: ")
with open('contagem.txt') as fin, open("update_teste.txt", "w") as out:
    for s in fin:
        out.write("0" + num + num2 + s[0:12] + s[14:19] + "\n")
```

Ou seja, para cada linha que leio de um, já escrevo a respectiva linha no outro. Detalhe para o `\n`, que adiciona a quebra de linha no final.

---

Se estiver usando Python >= 3.6, pode usar [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) em vez de concatenação:

```
with open('contagem.txt') as fin, open("update_teste.txt", "w") as out:
    for s in fin:
        out.write(f"0{num}{num2}{s[0:12]}{s[14:19]}\n")
```

Também mudei o modo de abertura do arquivo "update_teste.txt" de `w+` para apenas `w`, pois `w+` [abre o arquivo para leitura e escrita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036), mas como você só está escrevendo nele, não é necessário usar o `+`. Veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) para mais detalhes.

E retirei a terceira linha (`f = open("update_teste.txt","w+")`), pois não fazia sentido abrir o arquivo ali, para não usá-lo para nada e depois abri-lo novamente no segundo bloco `with`.

Comment: Bom dia, muito obrigado ! Atendeu minha necessidade perfeitamente.

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que se você apenas concatenar um `"\n"` no final da sua variável `new` o problema já estará resolvido!

Mais duas coisas: Aquela variável `f` que está abrindo o **update_teste.txt** pode estar atrapalhando o funcionamento, pois o arquivo não está sendo fechado.
Acredito que quando for passar a variável `new` pro writelines não é necessário o `str()`, pois a variável ja é construída por uma concatenação de strings.

Espero ter ajudado!